# Adding days to Date periodically in Java

Tags: java, days, date

I want to add days to the current date periodically.
For example, I every 10 seconds that passes, I want to add 1 day to the date today.
08/09/2019 after 10 seconds turns to 08/10/2019...I've already got a working timer, I just dont know how to implement the adding of days part

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        day = day + 1;
        model.setDay(day);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(model.getDay() ==1)
            c.setTime(date);

        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);

        String currentDate = dates2.format(c.getTime());
        String currentDate2 = dates2.format(d.getTime());
        model.setUpdateDate(currentDate);
        model.setUpdateDate2(currentDate2);

    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
long delay = 10000;
long intervalPeriod = 10000;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We love to help, but we need more info on your question. What have you tried? What  is your code? Please have a read here and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi ,Can you give more information about ur query.if possible please post the code what u have tried.

Comment: You've implemented working timer, that's fine. But why don't you post the code here so that someone here can help you with the adding of days part?

Comment: hello, i just edited my question, sorry for the incomplete details

Comment: Do you have to use java.util.Date etc? If you could use the java.time types, you'll find they're *much* nicer to work with.

Comment: yes, i have imported all the necessary packages like java.util.Date, SimpleDateFormat etc

Comment: No, I wasn't asking whether you'd imported them - I was asking whether you *had* to use those, or whether you could use the more modern types.

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the last in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also is your code working as you want it to? If not, what does it do instead? If you want help with a problem, it’s pretty crucial that you tell us what the problem is. And tell us very precisely, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) types instead of [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) and [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), which are considered *legacy types* since Java 8.

Here's an example that may suit you:

```java
public class CountingDays {

    private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountingDays countingDays = new CountingDays();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                countingDays.date = countingDays.date.plusDays(1);
                System.out.println(countingDays.date);
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        long delay = 0;
        long intervalPeriod = 10_000;

        timer.schedule(task, delay, intervalPeriod);
    }
}
```